# Find the area between the curves on the graph $y=\sin^2 kx \ $and $\ y=\cos^2 kx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I think I would know how to approach this question if it weren't for the constant $k$ in the equations. 
I would usually find the point of intersection between the two functions and set the $x$ co-ordinate of that as one of the boundaries but not sure how do that with the $k$ in the functions.

Comment: On which interval should the area between the curves be found? Also try substituting $z=kx$.

Comment: The trouble is that on $\Bbb R$ these functions intersect infinitely many times, so you have to specify some bounds for integration.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(x) = {\cos^2 kx}-{\sin^2 kx} = \cos 2kx \implies \int f(x) = \frac{\sin 2kx}{2k}$